# How to change number of cpu cores in VirtualBox virtual machine?

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machine, ubuntu-16.04

I have changed number of cpu cores with following command:

```
VBoxManage modifyvm "Ubuntu_16_04" --cpus 4
```

When I check with

```
vboxmanage showvminfo Ubuntu_16_04 --details
```

I get:

```
Number of CPUs:  4
```

But when I login onto guest machine:

```
cat /proc/cpuinfo
```

Result is:

```
cpu cores   : 1
```

Host and guest machines are ubuntu server 16.04.
What could be a problem?
Thank you

Comment: Did you reboot the VM after changing the setting?

Comment: @TeroKilkanen yes

Comment: Did you ever solve this?

Answer (score 0):

For this is not answered yet, short answer:

The cpu additionally has to be set "online" in the guest.

just have a look at:

*https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/core-api/cpu_hotplug.html*

Regards
MK

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1097611)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).